nmap doesnt see ip from my socket written in fasm
nmap doesn't see socket ip(192.168.0.17)
(assembly is fasm)
i tried with little endian,but it doesnt work anyway. probably trouble in addr and port
i wrote my code by help chromium os and i dont see any troubles with it here..
i didn't try with int 0x80(32bit) i need to use syscall
There is code:
format ELF64
section '.data'
    IPPROTO_TCP equ 0x06
    SOCK_STREAM equ 0x01
    AF_INET equ 0x02
    message db 'welcome',0xA,0
    message_lenght = $-message
    struc sockaddr sin_family,sin_port,sin_addr
    {
        .sin_family dw sin_family
        .sin_port dw sin_port; 1461
        .sin_addr dd sin_addr; 192.168.0.17
    }
    sockaddr_in sockaddr 0x02,0x05B5,0x1100A8C0
    sizeSockaddr = 0x02+0x05B5+0x1100A8C0
section '.text' executable
_start:
    ;socket
    mov rax,0x29 ;socket 
    mov rdi, AF_INET
    mov rsi, SOCK_STREAM
    mov rdx, IPPROTO_TCP
    syscall
    mov rbx,rax

    ;binding
    mov rax,0x31 ;bind
    mov rdi,rbx
    lea rsi,[sockaddr_in]
    mov rdx,sizeSockaddr
    syscall

    ;listening
    mov rax,0x32 ; listen
    mov rdi,rbx ;descriptor
    mov rsi,1
    syscall

    ;accept
    mov rax,43 ;accept
    mov rdi,rbx ;descriptor
    syscall
    ;welcome
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1;sys_write
    mov rsi,message 
    mov rdx,message_lenght
    syscall

    ;close socket
    mov rax,3 ;close
    mov rbx,rdi
    syscall

    ;exit program
    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall


Your sizeSockaddr is extremely suspicious ... you added up the values not the sizes.

Have you tried running strace ./a.out to decode the system calls your program makes and see if they succeed?

You need equ 8 or sizeSockaddr = 8, not dq 8 since you're using the symbol "address" as an immediate for things like mov rdx,sizeSockaddr.  Look at the final arg to bind in your strace output; it's a huge number because you passed a data-section address instead of 8.  If that wasn't obvious, write a C version and strace it to see what the system-call args should be.  Also, does FASM's struct support not let you have it calculate the size of your struc sockaddr for you so you don't have to hard-code 8?

bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(46341), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.17")}, 16) = -1 EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address) 
i made "sizeSockaddr equ 16"
when i change value to "sizeSockaddr dq 8" @PeterCordes

Are you trolling?  dw + dw + dd is 8 bytes.  Have you not tried sizeSockaddr = 8 like I suggested at the start of my previous comment?  That's valid FASM syntax for defining a numeric constant, and 8 bytes is the size of the socket-address struct you're passing to the kernel, so the size arg should be that value.  Passing 16 is probably what made the kernel think the address isn't valid, either looking at bytes past the end, or that the size doesn't match the size AF_INET should imply.

socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3 bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sa_data="\265\5\300\250\0\21"}, 8) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument) listen(3, 1)                            = 0 accept(3, 0x1, 0x8 @PeterCordes

Trying an example in C, turns out the actual struct sockaddr_in definition does have size 16 not 8, with an unsigned char sin_zero[8]; at the end.  (Instead of digging through headers, I compiled an example https://godbolt.org/z/5nc3zq9Pa with gcc -g and used GDB's ptype on the variable and its members, and strace shows bind(..., 16).) So that's why you got EINVAL with sizes other than 16, and EADDRNOTAVAIL with size 16.  Presumably you ran this on  a machine that doesn't have an interface with address 192.168.0.17 or port 46341 was already in use.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=functions-bind-bind-name-socket documents the sin_zero member and says it must be set to zero, so perhaps that's what you need.  The  And apparently it's not just a quirk of Linux; that doc is for zOS not Linux, but still POSIX socket API.  The example I copied from (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-4041/6j3r8iu2l/index.html) didn't do that, though, they had the struct sockaddr_in as a local var and never zeroed the whole thing or wrote that member, but it might have just happened to work with stack memory starting zeroed.

Interestingly, on Linux making a non-zero element in sin_zero[] doesn't cause bind to fail.  https://godbolt.org/z/GzjnPdPPW on my desktop run under strace still shows bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(31239), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0

yeah,ty @PeterCordes!
